# searching for a value in a binary search tree

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, binary-search-tree

I am working on a function that searches a templated binary search tree for a value with a given key and then returns a pointer to that data value. If the given key doesn't exist in the tree, the pointer it returns should point to NULL. So far I have:

```
template <typename Item, typename Key>
Item* BSTree<Item,Key>::search(const Key& key) const {
    Item* entry = NULL;
    Node* cursor = root;
    while(cursor != NULL) {
        if(key > cursor->data) 
            cursor = cursor->right;
        else if(key < cursor->data)
            cursor = cursor->left;
        else
            entry = cursor->data;
    }
    return entry;
}
```

But I get errors when I try and run it that say I can't convert from Item to Item*. I've always had trouble with pointers and can't figure out a way to fix these errors.

Comment: What line is the error on? What's the definition of `Node`?

Comment: Node is a structure with two pointers to other nodes, left and right. It also contains a templated data variable of type Item. The error was occurring on the line where i set entry = cursor->data. After attempting to fix it and then putting it back to normal I no longer get that error though. The program now compiles and then exits saying entry is being used without being initialized.

Comment: This seems weird: if(key > cursor->data) key is of type Key and data of type Item. Also answering whether you should just do entry = &(cursor->data) or whether your definition of the Node is problematic is impossible without seeing the definition for Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `entry = cursor->data;` you apparently need `entry = &(cursor->data);`.

Also note that once you find your item, you probably want to return it immediately, not continue traversing the tree looking at more items.